# select color attributes via python in blender

Tags: python, colors, blender, vertex

Is it possible to select color attributes in blender with python? Idea is to do the same like clicking on the vertex color in viewport. The goal is to make the colors visible in the viewport.

My current approach looks like this:

```
# accessing color attributes
test_1 = bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].color_attributes['test_1']
test_2 = bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].color_attributes['test_2']
        
# try to change selection
bpy.ops.geometry.color_attribute_render_set(name="test_2")
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Is there an easy approach to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a material like this:

```
def create_mat():
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="test")
    obj.data.materials.append(mat)
    mat.use_nodes = True
    mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeVertexColor")
    mat.node_tree.nodes["Color Attribute"].layer_name = "test_1"

    input = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs["Base Color"]
    output = mat.node_tree.nodes["Color Attribute"].outputs["Color"]
    mat.node_tree.links.new(input, output)

def change_mat():
    mat = bpy.data.materials["test"]
    mat.node_tree.nodes["Color Attribute"].layer_name = "test_2"

create_mat()
change_mat()
```